# ListView OnClicklistener Returns Only single json item value

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-volley

I have created a listview which will display some youtube video list (title, thumbnail, videocode) from json using volley library. List is displayed as I expected. Then I implemented onclick listener for list view. Here is the code

```
// Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setPYear(obj.getString("time"));
                            videocode = (obj.getString("videocode"));


                            //movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                //    .doubleValue());
                            //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                          //  JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                      for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));                              }
                            //movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent videoplayer = new Intent(Videos.this, VideoPlayer.class);
            //String videocode = null;
            videoplayer.putExtra("videocode", videocode);
            startActivity(videoplayer);
            finish();


        }
    });
```

So that after clicking on list item, another activity opens and plays the video. To play the video, youtube video code is required, that I am getting from Json and using putExtra I am transferring value to player activity.

The problem I am facing
Clicking on anyvideo plays in listview plays 1st video only. Means suppose list is showing 2 videos - Video1 and Video2. Naturally, clicking on video1 should play video1 and clicking on video2 should play video 2. But what happening is either I click on Video1 or Video2 or Video3, Player is playing video1 only..

Here is The JSON file
http://angelqr.cf/api.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the videocode from the movielist. At first add the videocode for every movie individually.

```
movie.setVideocode(obj.getString("videocode"));
 //videocode = (obj.getString("videocode"));
```

Then make a function for fetching the particular movie's videocode.

```
public String getVideocode(int position) {
  return movieList.get(position).getVideocode();
}
```

Then call it from your listener's code.

```
videoplayer.putExtra("videocode", getVideocode(position));
```